# XCode C Compiler Error Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers Expected ')'

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile C code and integrate it with Objective-C and Swift.  The C code is the ImageMagick library.

```
typedef struct _ChannelMoments
{
  double
    I[32];

  PointInfo
    centroid,
    ellipse_axis;

  double
    ellipse_angle,
    ellipse_eccentricity,
    ellipse_intensity;
} ChannelMoments;
```

The errors are on the line I[32];
Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers Expected ')'

Here are two photos of the issue

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't post images of code! Post as text!

Comment: In my opinion, the image is more informative, complete, and simple to both look at and paste.

Comment: See the site rules! And pasting text out of an image is not really "simple".

Comment: That is true.  But my reasoning was just that I'd have to specify where the error occurred, and the context is difficult to capture.

Comment: See, I will not further discuss this. Point is, this site has certain rules one has to follow. If you don't agree, this is your problem. Open a meta and try changing these rules. But until then: post text as text! Afaik copy/paste also works on the Mac with 4 keypresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with that line, but of course, I don't see the whole picture.  A few things to try:

- Delete everything between `double` and `I`, insert just a single
  space and see if that changes anything.
- Rename I to something else, e.g. `JUNK`, and see if that error goes
  away.  Other errors are likely to show up, though.  It is possible
  that `I` is `#defined` somewhere in some strange way.
- Change `PointInfo` to some other type, e.g. `int`.  Again, this will
  break the code elsewhere, but this is a test to see if `PointInfo` is
  the problem.

A word of warning: if you are trying to integrate C with Swift, you are likely to run into problems more interesting than this one.  Good luck.

Comment: I have attempted all three with a clean and build in between each one, but thanks for the attempt

Comment: Actually, renaming I works.  Changing "I" to "test" or "a" allows it to compile, and it doesn't seem like other parts of the code try to reference it or something.